# How can I test which page sent an AJAX request in my create.js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two different pages in my app that call an AJAX request to add a new phone_number (*to a `key_contact`*). These are the companies page (`key_contact belongs_to company`) and the sales_opportunity page (*where the sales_opportunity has_many key_contacts through sale_contacts*). Both pages have a table of `key_contacts` that I want to reload once the phone_number is added. I want to use the `create.js.erb` file to reload ONLY the table that should be on the page (*the table on sales_opportunities is different to the one on the companies page*). As such I need to test the URL of the page that sends the AJAX request and then render a partial accordingly. I've tried the below, but it isn't working. Can anyone help me work out why?

```
//update the key contact table with the new phone number, and close the modal
$('#phone_number_modal').modal('hide')
    .clear_previous_errors();
resetForm($('#new_phone_number'));
$input = $('#phone_number_error');
$input.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.warning-block').html('');
//render the newly added key contact to the table if the AJAX call succeeded

<% if (URI(request.referer).path == '/companies') %>
$('#key-contacts-table-div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/key_contacts_table')%>");
<% end %>

<% if (URI(request.referer).path == '/sales_opportunities') %>
$('#sale-contacts-table-div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'sale_contacts/table')%>");
<% end %>
$('.alert').remove();
$('#key-contacts').DataTable({
    retrieve: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `referer`, you can just add an extra `params` in your url, let's say you call it `:action_type`. Then in your controller, you can do:

```
class AAAController < ActionController::Base
  def your_action
    if params[:action_type] == "companies"
      render "create_1"
    elsif params[:action_type] == "sales_opportunities"
      render "create_2"
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can put different logic in `create_1.js.erb` or `create_2.js.erb` separately.

Comment: Thanks - but where does this code belong? Is it in the Phone_Numbers Controller?

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't use the exact answer, as I wasn't too sure how to. Instead I put a variable in the create controller action to determine which route the request had come from, then tested that variable to determine which of my create.js.erb files I needed to render. Works perfectly.